# How to resolve Angular Error with async pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

I am currently experiencing a problem with angular,
if i use a several pipe in addition to async pipe like that :

```
      <p>Mis à jour : {{ lastUpdate | async | date: 'yMMMMEEEEd' | uppercase }}</p>
```

the code can't compile and i have this error :

> Error: src/app/app.component.html:5:39 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
> Overload 1 of 3, '(value: string | number | Date, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
> Overload 2 of 3, '(value: null | undefined, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): null', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null | undefined'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'null'.
> Overload 3 of 3, '(value: string | number | Date | null | undefined, format?: string | undefined, timezone?: string | undefined, locale?: string | undefined): string | null', gave the following error.
> Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number | Date | null | undefined'.
> Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

any idea where the problem may come from?

```
lastUpdate = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const date = new Date();
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            resolve(date);
        }, 2000
    );
});
```

Comment: This is not the issue with chaining pipes. your lastUpdate variable is unknown. Share complete code. From where is lastUpdate value is coming?

Comment: the problem comes from this :" Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'Date'.", you need to make sure that date variable has a Date type

Comment: i add the code part where i create lastUpdate

Comment: off topic, but this is the short version of your code: `new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000, new Date()));` setTimeout supports function arguments for the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a promise without specifying, which type the resolved value should have, therefore it is typed as `unknown`. However, the date pipe does not accept type `unknown`.

Add type `Date` to the promise like the following:

```
lastUpdate = new Promise<Date>( //...
```